# Multiple concurrent threads with web queries issue

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, .net-core

i'm building quite complex concurrent system and stumbled upon weird issue. I'll try to be simple.

1. I have a single instance console app on .net core 2.1
2. I have single HttpClient instance
3. I set following params:
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
   System.Net.ServicePointManager.ReusePort = true; HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ConnectionClose = true;
   HttpClient.SetBearerToken(SOME_TOKEN);
4. I have a thread **(A)** that constantly creates up to 30 new concurrent threads with a single HTTP GET query inside using **ThreadPool/new Thread()** (tried both) and puts results into ConcurrentQueue variable.
5. I have another thread **(B)** that reads from queue and constantly creates up to 30 new concurrent threads with a single HTTP POST query inside.

The problem is that I get folowing workflow:

1. The A thread works well, feedeing queue with the results. All threads are running fine.
2. The B thread starts to create child threads for POST somewhat after the A thread start.
3. The A thread finishes its work, all threads are completed. At this point all the threads created by B thread are hanging on the **await client.PostAsync()** method.
4. App hangs for about 10 seconds.
5. VS log shows multiple **The thread 0x35e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).** messages persuming the previously used threads are freeing. Why so long?!
6. App hangs for additinal 20 seconds
7. The first threads created by B thread starts to fail and all other B threads then begin to execute normally.

Tried:

1. Lowering concurrent thread count to 5-10 at a time solves the problem but completely ruin the concurrent performance.
2. I see the the threads count in a log and there is no overflow, 30 threads max at a time for A and B (aprox 60 at maximum)
3. Tried to lower **System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit** param but it won't help.

Looks like something is blocking POST queries and then they just rush again normally. Please advice on this issue. Thank you.

PS: I work with **Flickr** queries. Could it be some of their access restrictions? The POST hang looks weird anyway it just hangs without a single entry pass.

Comment: So you may have up to 60+ threads? That sounds like too many, I would expect a performance hit with all the context switching between those threads. It may be better to only use 5-10 threads and to understand and fix the slow performance with that number of threads. More are more threads is not necessarily better!

Comment: May be I'm too optimistic about how many threads a modern PC can handle, but 5-10 seems a low number to me. I hoped I can get more, and as I've said it works fine with GET query threads.

Comment: A modern PC can handle lots of threads, but not necessarily efficiently. Your CPU can only physically run a few concurrent executions (depending on the number of cores, contention for shared resources etc); adding more threads can just make performance worse as the CPU has to context switch between them and it increases resource contention. E.g., a design where B threads are awaiting for long periods seems suspect to me--these threads are idle and maybe could be doing other useful work instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Polyfun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181315/polyfun), it was a good idea to limit app to less amount of threads constantly running instead of endless creation of hundreds of threads.

Though the real reason behind the slowdown was the resource block when some of the disposable resources during the queries has not been disposed. Including the **HttpWebResponse** entitities which were left intact by lower level code managed by customer.